# Some List items not visible

Tags: watir-webdriver

I can find 2 items in a list using:

`br.span(:text, "Customer").click`

But the others give me a `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError`. It seems a bit odd that some items in the list i can select and some Watir can see. Below is the html. I can select Telecom Profile but not Opportunity. Any thoughts on why one can be seen but not the other?

```
<TD style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; PADDING-TOP: 3px" id=apy0m1i2ITD vAlign=center width="100%" noWrap align=left>
  <SPAN style="MARGIN: 0px 13px">Opportunity</SPAN>
</TD>
</TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>


<TD style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; PADDING-TOP: 3px" id=apy0m1i3ITD vAlign=center width="100%" noWrap align=left>
  <SPAN style="MARGIN: 0px 13px">Telecom Profile</SPAN>
</TD>
</TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
```

Comment: I see no span text matching "Customer". Are you sure that's what you're looking for? Did you post the right HTML?

Comment: I apologize, a bit confusing. The example should have been br.span(:text, "Telecom Profile").click. What is odd is that 2 items in the list can be found and the rest cannot. My drop down list contains Customer, Contact, Telecom Profle, Activity and a few more.  I guess I would expect the script sees all in the list or none.

Comment: Based on the exception, watir is finding the element. The issue is that the element is not visible. Can you post a screenshot of the page?

Comment: Plus, it might be a good idea to include more of the HTML, since it seems likely that there's some context missing from your excerpt.

Comment: Selecting a span via text works for me. I think WebDriver cannot click an element if it's not visible, so perhaps some CSS or script on the page is causing it to be hidden or not visible?  If you are doing something which causes the page to update, you might need to wait until that element is visible before clicking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you say 'Select from a list' but there is no HTML select element present in the HTML you show, just tables and rows.  So that makes me think your 'list' control is some kind of javascript animated widget, from jQuery or some similar library.

The way a lot of those work is that they build up the stuff that looks like say a pulldown menu, but then set the class such that the stuff is not visible.  When you do something (like click-on or mouseover) to the top of the pulldown, it changes the class to one that is rendered visible by CSS.  Often they use something called a psuedo-class that is triggered by the mouse being over the item, so once the menu is displayed, it stays displayed as long as the mouse is over it.

Automating these can be particularly tricky because webdriver does not move the actual mouse pointer around to create mouseover or hover events.  So you can do something to cause a menu to display, like clicking at the top of the menu, but then very rapidly the browser can detect that the mouse is not over the thing, and boom, it's hidden again.

By design, pretty much anything using webdriver to drive the browser (watir-webdriver, Selenium, Capybara) will not click or interact with an element that is not 'present' from the perspective of the user (which is to say visible and enabled).  Normally this is good, if the user could not click it, then why should the automation tool get to click it?   This is likely the source of the 'not visible' message, that's webdriver saying 'hey I can find this thing in the DOM, but it's not visible for the user, so you don't get to click it.

I usually troubleshoot such pages from IRB, firing in the watir-webdriver commands that I think would make the menu appear, followed by the one to click the element..  If you can get that to work, then likely it will work at scripting speed.

Sometimes you need to use the 'when present' decorator, if for example something will become visible or come into being as a result of an earlier action, and you don't want to try to interact with it too soon.

```
browser.span(:text => "Customer").when_present.click
```

That's a little more elegant than @TrinitronX's suggestion, but is basically the same thing

That approach won't help you however if the problem is that the element appears and disappears between one line of code being executed and the next line of code, e.g. if it goes away too fast.

In that case you might have to resort to something like executing some javascript to alter the style for the element to force it to be visible.  Or you could try manually firing the onclick event at the element and see if that causes the javascript to respond as if you had clicked it.

Without seeing the site itself, or a sample site that has the same control on it, it's sometimes hard to know what the best solution will be for manipulating the element

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver cannot click an element if it's not visible.

Is the page changing before the element becomes visible?  If so, try this:

```
br.wait_until { br.span(:text => 'Customer').visible? }
br.span(:text, "Customer").click
```